# Connect Akka Streams to JMS

Tags: scala, jms, akka-stream, webmethods

I'm trying to connect to a Universal Messaging queue (by Software AG) via Akka Streams. I have looked in the doc of [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/camel.html) regarding the Camel integrations, but I'm struggling with understanding how the components fit together. For instance, do I have to use ActiveMQ as a broker?

I have previously set up a connection via MQTT (and Spark's MQTTUtils) but since I want to try out Akka I don't think MQTT via TCP is necessary. [It is recommended}(http://tech.forums.softwareag.com/techjforum/posts/list/55887.page) that I use JMS instead of another protocol, especially with third-party tools. Hence my question regarding the proper setup of Akka Streams to UM via JMS.

Answer (score 3):

The recommendation is to move away from Camel and leverage a fully reactive, akka-streams based solution. The Alpakka project was born to collect akka-streams compatible connectors in one bundle.

It currently contains a JMS connector (as well as AMQP and MQTT connectors). Further info:

- Official launch [article](http://blog.akka.io/integrations/2016/08/23/intro-alpakka)
- [Alpakka home](http://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/index.html)
- [JMS connector docs](http://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/jms.html)